# How to add fisheye effect with imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to add fisheye effect with imagemagick to photo as its done now with php script. It looks bad and I want to try maybe imagemagick can do it better.

[original image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdo3vlaef0oraoj/_y_7_y70etlm4ask_jpg.jpg)

[php script result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1viynmy59fu66ri/_y_7_81ca45981b4ece2b9f9468a6053e7714_edit_y70etlm4ask_jpg.jpg)

I was trying to apply Barrel distorsion and [fisheye2rect](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/fisheye2rect/index.php) script but cant find proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash unix shell script, spherize, that uses ImageMagick that can be called using PHP exec(). See http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Using your input image:

```
spherize -a 1 _y_7_y70etlm4ask_jpg result2.jpg
```

[image]

or

```
spherize -a 1 -b image _y_7_y70etlm4ask_jpg result2.jpg
```

[image]

Alternately, see my script, fisheye.

```
fisheye -f fullframe -i 150 _y_7_y70etlm4ask_jpg result3.jpg
```

[image]